# Loading different QWidgets dependant on highlighting row of QTableWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qtabwidget

Having a `QTableWidgets` with a list of tables and two additional classes `Combocells` and `Groupcells`. They are shown with `QTabWidget`. I want to click and highlight a row or cell in the table then the two classes `Combocells` and `Groupcells` refreshs and loads into `QTabWidget` according to row of table.

The structure of files.

> - Main.py
> - Tablecells.py
> - Combocells.py
> - Groupcells.py

**Visualisation**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

> I have updated the code, signal and slot catch row number and send it.
>   Despite by clicking on cells `Data and Value` tabs add to tabwidgets and
>   removes, when `row 0` is selected. what I do not get is when `row 1` is
>   selected, well `Data and Value` tabs add to widget, make some changes in
>   `combobox` and `Qlineedit` inside Data and Value to see, when `row 2` is
>   clicked, would `Data and Value` really add to tabwidget from beginning.
>   I notice it does not update. I have tried with `addTab` and `insertTab`
>   with `self.update()`, still does not really process in a way I want to
>   do.
>
> Could anyone know how to fix this issue?
>   Review this piece of script which has problem.

```
class Tabwidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super( Tabwidget, self).__init__() 
-----------------------
   @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int) 
   def rowselected_tables(self, row):
        print('Row {} is selected.'.format(row))
        if row > 0:
            self.update()
            #self.Tab.addTab( self.Combo, 'Data')
            #self.Tab.addTab( self.Group, 'Values')
            self.Tab.insertTab( 1, self.Combo, 'Data')
            self.Tab.insertTab( 2, self.Group, 'Values')
```

I want to load data and values tabs accordingly to number of `rows`. for example when user clicks and highlights a certain row inside the table the classes are loaded and any change in `Data and Values` for that row should remain, when user highlight another row then new Data and Value appears, but in case of return to previous highlighted and clicked row or cell any previous changes in `Data and Values` would appear again.

I want to print something like.

```
Row x is highligted: Data : ( L6, 0,10) and Value: (10)
```

[image]

**UPDATED:**

**Main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from Combocells import Combocells 
from Groupcells import Groupcells 
from Tablecells import Tablecells 

class Tabwidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super( Tabwidget, self).__init__() 
        self.sizeHint()
        Tab = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()

        self.Table = Tablecells()
        self.Combo = Combocells()
        self.Group = Groupcells()

        Tab.addTab( self.Table, 'Tables')
        #Tab.addTab( self.Combo, 'Data')
        #Tab.addTab( self.Group, 'Values')

        self.Table.rownumber.connect(self.rowselected_tables)


        self.Tab.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Georgia",9,QtGui.QFont.Normal))

        vboxlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vboxlayout.addWidget(self.Tab)
        self.setLayout(vboxlayout)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int) 
    def rowselected_tables(self, row):
        print('Row {} is selected.'.format(row))
        if row > 0:
            self.update()
            #self.Tab.addTab( self.Combo, 'Data')
            #self.Tab.addTab( self.Group, 'Values')
            self.Tab.insertTab( 1, self.Combo, 'Data')
            self.Tab.insertTab( 2, self.Group, 'Values')

        else:
            for n in [2,1]:
                self.Tab.removeTab( n )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Tabwidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**UPDATED:**

**Tablecells.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

class Tablecells(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    data = [("1", "Login",       "1", "test_login_s"), 
        ("2", "Logout",      "1", "test_logout_s"), 
        ("3", "User > Edit", "1", "test_user_edit_s")]
    rownumber = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Tablecells, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Georgia",9,QtGui.QFont.Normal))
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 4)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Id", "Test name", "Owner", "Type"])
        self.tableWidget.cellClicked.connect(self.cellClick)
        self.setTableWidget()
        self.getrow()

        self.lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.tableWidget)

    def setTableWidget(self):    
        for r, (_id, _name, _owner, _type) in enumerate(self.data):
            it_id     = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(_id)
            it_name   = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(_name)
            it_owner  = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(_owner)
            it_type = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(_type)

            self.tableWidget.insertRow(self.tableWidget.rowCount())
            for c, item in enumerate((it_id, it_name, it_owner, it_type)):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(r, c, item)

    def cellClick(self, row, column):
        self.row = row
        self.column = column     
        print(self.row , self.column)
        self.rownumber.emit(self.row)

    def getrow(self):
        it = self.tableWidget.currentRow()
        print(it)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Tablecells()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Combocells.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Combocells(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Combocells, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Helvetica", 10, QtGui.QFont.Normal, italic=False))

        self.combo_exclass = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.combo_exclass.addItems([" Type 1       "," Type 2       "," Type 3       "," Type 4       "," Type 5       "])

        self.combo_lclass = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.combo_lclass.addItems(["L2","L4","L6","L8"])

        self.combo_vct = QtWidgets.QComboBox()

        self.combo_vct.addItems(["0.10","0.20","0.30","0.40",
                                        "0.50","0.60","0.70"])

        self.combo_in = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.combo_in.addItems(["Class1","Class2","Class3"])        

        self.tbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.exclass = QtWidgets.QLabel("Class1: ")
        self.tbox.addWidget(self.exclass)
        self.tbox.addWidget(self.combo_exclass)


        self.mtbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.lclass = QtWidgets.QLabel("Class2: ")

        self.mtbox.addWidget(self.lclass)
        self.mtbox.addWidget(self.combo_lclass)


        self.mbbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.vct = QtWidgets.QLabel("Class3: ")
        self.mbbox.addWidget(self.vct)
        self.mbbox.addWidget(self.combo_vct)

        self.bbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.inl = QtWidgets.QLabel("Class4: ")
        self.bbox.addWidget(self.inl)
        self.bbox.addWidget(self.combo_in)

        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.grid.addLayout(self.tbox, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.grid.addLayout(self.mtbox, 1, 0)
        self.grid.addLayout(self.mbbox, 2, 0)
        self.grid.addLayout(self.bbox, 3, 0)

        Environment_Group = QtWidgets.QGroupBox()
        Environment_Group.setTitle("&Group2")
        Environment_Group.setLayout(self.grid)

        vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vlay.addWidget(Environment_Group)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Combocells()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Groupcells.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Groupcells(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Groupcells, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Helvetica", 10, QtGui.QFont.Normal, italic=False))      

        self.c_lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        fctd = "One\n\nTwo\n\nThree"
        con_strength = QtWidgets.QLabel(fctd)
        self.value = QtWidgets.QLineEdit('Test')
        self.c_lay.addWidget(con_strength)
        self.c_lay.addWidget(self.value, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)


        self.combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.combo.addItems(["10","12","14","16"])

        self.hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.con = QtWidgets.QLabel("Number: ")
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.con)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.combo)

        self.vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vlay.addLayout(self.hbox)
        self.vlay.addLayout(self.c_lay)
        self.vlay.addStretch()

        Concrete_Group = QtWidgets.QGroupBox()
        Concrete_Group.setTitle("&GroupA")
        Concrete_Group.setLayout(self.vlay)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(Concrete_Group)

        self.comth = ["10","12","14","16"]
        self.combo.activated.connect(self.setdatastrength)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def setdatastrength(self, index):
        value = self.comth[index]
        self.display_data(value)


    def display_data(self, value):
        try:
            f = value
            f_value = "{}"
            self.value.setText(f_value.format(f))

        except ValueError:
            print("Error")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Groupcells()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I really do not know how to achieve that. It might be some special scripts in PyQT5 to do the task. I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I read it several times and didn’t understand what you want to update?
For example: if you click on the cells of a row with index 1,
what do you want to see inside the `Value` tab?

Comment: @S.Nick. what I want to see is, when cells of row with index 1 clicks, Data and Value tabs remember the values for example combo value for class 3 is changed to 0.30, after selecting cells of row 2, values inside Combobox and others in Data and Value tabs refresh and reset for example combo value to 0.10. Hope I have explained well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want the "Group" and "Combo" tabs to remember the values you set for a specific row and restore these values when you select the row again after having selected a different row. In that case you could do something like below (`GroupCells.py` and `ComboCells.py` are the same as before)

**In Main.py**

```
class Tabwidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super( Tabwidget, self).__init__()
        self.sizeHint()
        self.Tab = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()

        self.data = [("1", "Login", "1", "test_login_s"),
                ("2", "Logout", "1", "test_logout_s"),
                ("3", "User > Edit", "1", "test_user_edit_s")]

        self.combos = []
        self.groups = []
        self.Table = Tablecells()
        for row in self.data:
            self.addRow(row)

        self.Tab.addTab( self.Table, 'Tables')
        self.Table.rownumber.connect(self.rowselected_tables)
        self.Tab.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Georgia",9,QtGui.QFont.Normal))

        vboxlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vboxlayout.addWidget(self.Tab)
        self.setLayout(vboxlayout)

    def addRow(self, data):
        self.Table.addRow(data)
        self.combos.append(Combocells())
        self.groups.append(Groupcells())

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def rowselected_tables(self, row):
        print('Row {} is selected.'.format(row))
        while self.Tab.count() > 1:
            self.Tab.removeTab(self.Tab.count()-1)
        self.Tab.addTab(self.combos[row], 'Combo')
        self.Tab.addTab(self.groups[row], 'Group')
```

**In TableCells.py**

```
class Tablecells(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    rownumber = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Tablecells, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Georgia",9,QtGui.QFont.Normal))
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 4)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Id", "Test name", "Owner", "Type"])
        self.tableWidget.cellClicked.connect(self.cellClick)
        self.getrow()

        self.lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.tableWidget)

    def addRow(self, data):
        _id, _name, _owner, _type = data
        it_id     = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(_id)
        it_name   = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(_name)
        it_owner  = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(_owner)
        it_type = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(_type)

        self.tableWidget.insertRow(self.tableWidget.rowCount())
        for c, item in enumerate((it_id, it_name, it_owner, it_type)):
            self.tableWidget.setItem(self.tableWidget.rowCount()-1, c, item)

    def cellClick(self, row, column):
        self.row = row
        self.column = column
        print(self.row , self.column)
        self.rownumber.emit(self.row)

    def getrow(self):
        it = self.tableWidget.currentRow()
        print(it)
```

In this example I create a number of `ComboCells` and `GroupCells` widget equal to the number of rows in the table, and add these widgets to `self.Tab` if the corresponding row is selected. In order to do this I've moved the responsibility of adding the data to the table from `TableCells` to `TabWidget` and replaced `TableCells.setTableWidget()` with two methods: `TableCells.addRow()` and `TabWidget.addRow()`. The `ComboCells` and `GroupCells` widgets are created in `TabWidget.addRow` and added to `self.combos` and `self.groupcells`, respectively. These widgets are then added and removed to `self.Tab`  in `TabWidget.rowselected_tables()`.

Comment: Perfect it works like a charm.. Thank you so much. :)